# How can we run kml file in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6-maps

as we all know that iOS6 is launched can any one tell how to display the kml file on map in iOS6.Earlier i was showing it on google maps.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that displaying the KML file should be no different.  My current mapkit project seamlessly upgraded to iOS6.  I would try just uploading Apple's sample code KMLViewer, compiling it and downloading to your device. It worked for me.